# Reactive-Forms: FormControl Validator from Parent in Child Component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

everyone,

I built my Reactive-Form with Angular 6.

Here I built the form in my ParentComponent with Validators:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: '
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName="address">
        <child formControlName="street"></child>
        <child formControlName="housenumber"></child>
        <child formControlName="city"></child>
    </div>
  </form>'
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      address: this.formBuilder.group({
        street: new FormControl(null,[Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(40), Validators.required]),
        housenumber: new FormControl(null,[Validators.pattern("[0-9]{7}", Validators.required]),
        city: new FormControl(null,[ Validators.required]),
      })
    });  
  }

  onSubmit(){
    log.console("submit");
  }
}
```

for the input fields I want to make a ChildComponent that gives the user more information and I don't have the same code multiple times.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '
  <label>I´m a label</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="_model"></input>
  {{_model.errors}}
  ',
   providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    _model;
    onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  constructor() {
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model;
  }

  set model(val) {
    this._model = val;
    this.onChange(val);
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value) {
      this._model = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

The input value is successfully transferred to the parent component.
But how can I check the validation of the FormControl from the parent in the child ?

Comment: The easier thing to do is pass in your "parent" formGroup instance to the child control(s), and then add the formGroup or formControl instance(s) in the child to the parent's form group. This way you end up with a single form group instance and don't need any parent/child communication. Basically, compose your form from multiple components.